# HTML datalist with price range per option

Tags: javascript, html, html-datalist

I have created a datalist to filter apartments according to number of bedrooms and then by price. My issue is I need to indicate the price range per step instead of just one price per step. I have tried different datalists and have tried adding values, labels ect to no avail.

Below is a screenshots of where the price range needs to be showen instead of just the one price as it shows now (R1600000) it needs to show R1600000 to R3180000.

[Datalist to filter rooms and prices](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iB7hw.png)

[image]

The JS and HTML looks like this:

```js
var pricesarr = [
["A","STUDIO","2nd ","9","49.8","-","After Hours",1675000,"SF","unit_a.html"],
["A","STUDIO","3rd ","9","49.8","-","After Hours",1675000,"SF","unit_a.html"],
["A","STUDIO","4th ","9","49.8","-","After Hours",1675000,"SF","unit_a.html"],
["A","STUDIO","5th ","9","49.8","-","After Hours",1675000,"SF","unit_a.html"],
["A","STUDIO","6th ","9","49.8","-","After Hours",1675000,"SF","unit_a.html"],
["A","STUDIO","3rd ","9","49.8","± 4","1",1815000,"WF","unit_a.html"],
["A","STUDIO","4th ","9","49.8","± 4","1",1875000,"WF","unit_a.html"],
["A","STUDIO","5th ","9","49.8","± 4","1",1935000,"WF","unit_a.html"],
["A","STUDIO","6th ","9","49.8","± 4","1",1995000,"WF","unit_a.html"],
["A","STUDIO","7th ","9","49.8","± 4","1",1995000,"WF","unit_a.html"],
["B","1 BED STRAIGHT","2nd ","7","49.6","4.2","1",1950000,"SF","unit_b.html"],
["B","1 BED STRAIGHT","3rd ","7","49.6","4.2","1",2010000,"SF","unit_b.html"],
["B","1 BED STRAIGHT","4th ","7","49.6","4.2","1",2070000,"SF","unit_b.html"],
["B","1 BED STRAIGHT","5th ","7","49.6","4.2","1",2130000,"SF","unit_b.html"],
["B","1 BED STRAIGHT","6th ","7","49.6","4.2","1",2190000,"SF","unit_b.html"],
["B","1 BED STRAIGHT","3rd ","10","49.6","4.2","1",2235000,"WF","unit_b.html"],
["B","1 BED STRAIGHT","4th ","10","49.6","4.2","1",2295000,"WF","unit_b.html"],
["B","1 BED STRAIGHT","5th ","10","49.6","4.2","1",2355000,"WF","unit_b.html"],
["B","1 BED STRAIGHT","6th ","10","49.6","4.2","1",2415000,"WF","unit_b.html"],
["B","1 BED STRAIGHT","7th ","10","49.6","4.2","1",2475000,"WF","unit_b.html"],
["C","1 BED ZIGZAG","2nd ","2","50.2","4.2","1",1975000,"SF","unit_c.html"],
["C","1 BED ZIGZAG","3rd ","2","50.2","4.2","1",2035000,"SF","unit_c.html"],
["C","1 BED ZIGZAG","4th ","2","50.2","4.2","1",2095000,"SF","unit_c.html"],
["C","1 BED ZIGZAG","5th ","2","50.2","4.2","1",2155000,"SF","unit_c.html"],
["C","1 BED ZIGZAG","6th ","2","50.2","4.2","1",2215000,"SF","unit_c.html"],
["C","1 BED ZIGZAG","3rd ","8","50.2","4.2","1",2275000,"WF","unit_c.html"],
["C","1 BED ZIGZAG","4th ","8","50.2","4.2","1",2335000,"WF","unit_c.html"],
["C","1 BED ZIGZAG","5th ","8","50.2","4.2","1",2395000,"WF","unit_c.html"],
["C","1 BED ZIGZAG","6th ","8","50.2","4.2","1",2455000,"WF","unit_c.html"],
["C","1 BED ZIGZAG","7th ","8","50.2","4.2","1",2515000,"WF","unit_c.html"],
["D","1 BED TRIANGLE","2nd ","1","55.1","4.8","1",2260000,"SF","unit_d.html"],
["D","1 BED TRIANGLE","3rd ","1","55.1","4.8","1",2320000,"SF","unit_d.html"],
["D","1 BED TRIANGLE","4th ","1","55.1","4.8","1",2380000,"SF","unit_d.html"],
["D","1 BED TRIANGLE","5th ","1","55.1","4.8","1",2440000,"SF","unit_d.html"],
["D","1 BED TRIANGLE","6th ","1","55.1","4.8","1",2500000,"SF","unit_d.html"],
["E","2 BED TRIANGLE","8th ","1","99.1","12.5 + 6.2","2",4778000,"SF","unit_e.html"],
["F","2 BED CORNER","2nd ","1","104.5","25.8 + 6.8","2",5525000,"SF","unit_f.html"],
["F","2 BED CORNER","3rd ","1","104.5","25.8 + 6.8","2",5625000,"SF","unit_f.html"],
["F","2 BED CORNER","4th ","1","104.5","25.8 + 6.8","2",5725000,"SF","unit_f.html"],
["F","2 BED CORNER","5th ","1","104.5","25.8 + 6.8","2",5825000,"SF","unit_f.html"],
["F","2 BED CORNER","6th ","1","104.5","25.8 + 6.8","2",5925000,"SF","unit_f.html"],
["F","2 BED CORNER","3rd ","1","104.5","25.8 + 6.8","2",6000000,"WF","unit_f.html"],
["F","2 BED CORNER","4th ","1","104.5","25.8 + 6.8","2",6100000,"WF","unit_f.html"],
["F","2 BED CORNER","5th ","1","104.5","25.8 + 6.8","2",6200000,"WF","unit_f.html"],
["F","2 BED CORNER","6th ","1","104.5","25.8 + 6.8","2",6300000,"WF","unit_f.html"],
["F","2 BED CORNER","7th ","1","104.5","25.8 + 6.8","2",6400000,"WF","unit_f.html"],
["G","2 BED CORNER EX 1","3rd ","1","113","26.6 + 6.9","2",6425000,"WF","unit_g.html"],
["G","2 BED CORNER EX 1","4th ","1","113","26.6 + 6.9","2",6525000,"WF","unit_g.html"],
["G","2 BED CORNER EX 1","5th ","1","113","26.6 + 6.9","2",6625000,"WF","unit_g.html"],
["G","2 BED CORNER EX 1","6th ","1","113","26.6 + 6.9","2",6725000,"WF","unit_g.html"],
["G","2 BED CORNER EX 1","7th ","1","113","26.6 + 6.9","2",6825000,"WF","unit_g.html"],
["H","2 BED CORNER EX 2","2nd ","1","111.7","17.4 + 6.9","2",5485000,"SF","unit_h.html"],
["H","2 BED CORNER EX 2","3rd ","1","111.7","17.4 + 6.9","2",5585000,"SF","unit_h.html"],
["H","2 BED CORNER EX 2","4th ","1","111.7","17.4 + 6.9","2",5685000,"SF","unit_h.html"],
["H","2 BED CORNER EX 2","5th ","1","111.7","17.4 + 6.9","2",6626000,"SF","unit_h.html"],
["H","2 BED CORNER EX 2","6th ","1","111.7","17.4 + 6.9","2",6725000,"SF","unit_h.html"],
["I","LOFT","8th ","16","74.9","4.2","2",3225000,"SF","unit_i.html"],
["I","LOFT","8th ","22","74.9","4.2","2",3525000,"WF","unit_i.html"],
["J","SPECIAL LOFT","7th (North)","1","79.1","16.2 + 4.2","2",4250000,"SF","unit_j.html"],
["J","SPECIAL LOFT","7th (South)","1","79.1","16.2 + 4.2","2",4250000,"SF","unit_j.html"],
["J","SPECIAL LOFT","9th ","5","79.1","16.2 + 4.2","2",4400000,"WF","unit_j.html"],
["K","SUPER LOFT","8th ","1","173.9","23.3 + 7.8 + 5.3 + 5","2",9150000,"SF","unit_k.html"],
["K","SUPER LOFT","9th ","1","173.9","23.3 + 7.8 + 5.3 + 5","2",9325000,"WF","unit_k.html"],
["L","SUPER LOFT EX 2","8th ","1","189.3","16.7 + 5.4 + 5.4","2",8750000,"SF","unit_l.html"],
["M","SUPER LOFT EX 2","9th ","1","194","26.6 + 6.9 + 5.3 + 5","2",9575000,"WF","unit_m.html"]

];

$(document).ready(function(){
 
 var scrollTop = 0,
        scrollEnterVal = 200,
        slidervalroom = 0,
        slidervalprice = 0,
        valfacing = "SF";

 $( document ).scroll(function(e) {
  var scrollTop = $(window).scrollTop();

  if(scrollTop + scrollEnterVal > advertAtop){            
            $("#mainimgA").addClass('animatedeffects');
            $("#advertA #description").removeClass("hide").addClass('animated fadeInDown');
            $("#description img").addClass("animated flipInY")
        }
        
        if(scrollTop + scrollEnterVal > advertBtop){
            
            $("#mainimgB").addClass('animatedeffects');
            $("#advertB #description").removeClass("hide").addClass('animated fadeInUp');
        }
  
  if(scrollTop + scrollEnterVal > advertCtop){
            
            $("#mainimgC").addClass('animatedeffects');
            $("#advertC #description").removeClass("hide").addClass('animated fadeInUp');
        }
 });    
    
    function filterPrices(rooms, price, facing){
        
        var roomAlpha = "A";
        
        if(rooms == 0)         roomAlpha = "A"; 
        else if(rooms == 1)    roomAlpha = "BCD";
        else if(rooms == 2)    roomAlpha = "EFGHIJ";
        else if(rooms == 3)    roomAlpha = "KLM";
        
        var filteredroomsarr = pricesarr.filter(function(value){
            if(roomAlpha.indexOf(value[0]) > -1) return value;
        });
        
        var filteredpricesarr = filteredroomsarr.filter(function(value){
            if(value[7] >= price) return value; 
        });
        
        var filteredfacingarr = filteredpricesarr.filter(function(value){
            if(value.indexOf(facing) > -1) return value; 
        });
        
        buildtable(filteredfacingarr);
    
    }
    
    function buildtable(arr){
        var eltable = $("#pricingtable");
        var str = "";
        
        for(var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++){

            str += "<tr>";           
            str += "<td>"+arr[i][2]+"</td>";
            str += "<td>"+arr[i][0]+"</td>";
            str += "<td>"+arr[i][3]+"</td>";
            str += "<td>"+arr[i][4]+"</td>";
            str += "<td>"+arr[i][5]+"</td>";
            str += "<td>"+arr[i][6]+"</td>";
            str += "<td>"+currentFormat(arr[i][7])+"</td>";
             str += "<td class='text-center'><a href='"+arr[i][9]+"' class='btn btn-default btn-md'>View Property</a></td>";
            str += "</tr>";
        }
        
        eltable.find("tbody").empty().html(str);
    }    
    
    function currentFormat(num){
        return 'R' + parseFloat(num, 10).toFixed(2).replace(/(\d)(?=(\d{3})+\.)/g, "$1,").toString();
    } 
    
    function initialize() {
        var mapCanvas = document.getElementById('map');
        var mapOptions = {
            center: new google.maps.LatLng(44.5403, -78.5463),
            zoom: 8,
            mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
        }
        var map = new google.maps.Map(mapCanvas, mapOptions)
    }
    
    
    $("#slider-rooms").on('change', function(e){

        slidervalroom = $(e.currentTarget).val();
        $("#pricevalRoom").text("Rooms : " + slidervalroom);

        filterPrices(slidervalroom, slidervalprice, valfacing);
    });
    
    $("#slider-price").on('change', function(e){
        slidervalprice = $(e.currentTarget).val();
        $("#pricevalPrice").text("Price : " + currentFormat(slidervalprice));
        filterPrices(slidervalroom, slidervalprice, valfacing);
    });
    
    $("input[type='radio']").on('change', function(e){
        valfacing = $(e.currentTarget).val();
        filterPrices(slidervalroom, slidervalprice, valfacing);
    });
    
    filterPrices(0, 1600000, "SF");

    
    //google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize); 
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="" class="container">
        <div id="pricing" class="row">
            <div class="col-md-12 pd-lr-lg">
                <div class="col-md-6">
                    <h2 class="pd-tp-md">UNITS</h2>

                    <p>Kgoro’s first residential project, Kgoro West, offers a mix of 13 designer apartments ranging from superior studio units to luxury super lofts. The units presented below are available for purchase, off-plan, maximising your investment and securing your home in Africa’s premier real estate development. Please use the sliders below to search either Square or West Street facing units against bedroom quantity and price range.</p>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-6">&nbsp;</div>
            </div>

            <div class="col-md-12 pd-lr-lg">
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-md-4">
                        <strong><p id="pricevalRoom">Rooms : Studio</p></strong>
                        <div class="pd-tb-md">
                            <input id="slider-rooms" type="range" min="0" max="3" step="1" value="0" list="steplist" />
                            <datalist id="steplist">
                                <option>Studio</option>
                                <option>1</option>
                                <option>2</option>
                                <option>3</option>

                            </datalist>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-md-4">
                        <strong><p id="pricevalPrice">Price : R1,600,000.00 to R3,180,000</p></strong>
                        <div class="pd-tb-md">
                            <input id="slider-price" type="range" min="1600000" max="9575000" step="1580000" value="1600000" list="markerticks" />
                            <datalist id="markerticks">
                                <option>1600000</option>
                                <option>3180000</option> 
                                <option>4760000</option>
                                <option>6340000</option>
                                <option>7920000</option>
                                <option>9500000</option>
                            </datalist>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-md-4">
                        <strong><p>Direction Facing</p></strong>
                        <div class="pd-tb-radio">
                            <label class="radio-inline">
                                <input type="radio" name="inlineRadioOptions" id="inlineRadio1" value="SF" checked> Square
                            </label>
                            <label class="radio-inline">
                                <input type="radio" name="inlineRadioOptions" id="inlineRadio2" value="WF"> West Street
                            </label>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>

                <div class="row pd-tp-sm pd-b-md pd-lr-sm">
                    <table class="table table-striped unit-table" id="pricingtable">
                        <thead>
                            <tr>
                                <th>Floor</th>
                                <th>Unit Type</th>
                                <th>Units</th>
                                <th>Internal (m²)</th>
                                <th>Balcony (m²)</th>
                                <th>Parking</th>
                                <th>Price</th>
                                <th class="text-center">View Property</th>
                            </tr>
                        </thead>

                        <tbody>

                        </tbody>



                    </table>
                </div>
            </div>

        </div>
    </div>
```